# About fractional ideal of localization

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I want to solve the following problem using only the fact that the fractional ideal forms a group, without equivalent definition of the Dedekind ring such as Krull dimension or unique factorizing of ideals.

> If $\mathfrak o$ is Dedekind ring and $\mathfrak p\in\text{Spec}(\mathfrak o)$, then localization $\mathfrak o_\mathfrak p$ is also Dedekind.

If the following property holds, then I think this problem would be easy to solve. I suspect this is true because ideals(not fractional) holds this property.

> Let $S$ be multiplicative subset $\mathfrak o\setminus\mathfrak p$. If $J\lhd\mathfrak o_\mathfrak p$, then there exists $I\lhd\mathfrak o$ such that $S^{-1}I=J$.

Is it valid? I know that every ideal is finitely generated, but I'm not sure that every **fractional** ideal is finitely generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer... in my own. I had missed something very important.

Answer follows:

Regarding $s^{-1}a\in\mathfrak o_\mathfrak p$ be element of $K$, then $\mathfrak o_\mathfrak p$ is subring of $K$ therefore $K$ is also quotient field of $\mathfrak o_\mathfrak p$.

Let $\mathfrak a$ be fractional ideal of $\mathfrak o_\mathfrak p$ then there exists $x\in K, J\lhd\mathfrak o_\mathfrak p$ such that $xJ=\mathfrak a$. Then there exists $I\lhd\mathfrak o$ such that $J=S^{-1}I$. Since $I$ itself is fractional ideal of $\mathfrak o$, therefore its inverse $I^{-1}$ is fractional ideal of $\mathfrak o$.

Thus, there exists $y\in K, I'\lhd\mathfrak o$ such that $yI'=I^{-1}$.

Since $S^{-1}(yI')=yS^{-1}I'$ and $S^{-1}I\cdot S^{-1}I^{-1}=S^{-1}(II^{-1})=S^{-1}\mathfrak o=\mathfrak o_\mathfrak p$, $\mathfrak a(x^{-1}yS^{-1}I')=xS^{-1}I\cdot x^{-1}S^{-1}(yI')=S^{-1}I\cdot S^{-1}I^{-1}=\mathfrak o_p$.

So every fractional ideal of $\mathfrak o_\mathfrak p$ has its inverse, so $\mathfrak o_\mathfrak p$ is Dedekind ring. $\blacksquare$